# ssh and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssh

I am running Eclipse Kepler on Mac OS 10.9.2 and I am trying to import an ssh2 public key, created with ssh-keygen so that I can use Egit in eclipse.

Unfortunately, when I am trying to load my public key (for which I did not set a passphrase) into Eclipse using Preferences->Network Connections->SSH2->Load Existing Key I get "Failed to load given key".

I know that this was a bug in 2005, but according to some sources it should have been fixed and I am wondering if anybody knows anything about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not import your public, but your private key. That is the one used for connections.

Comment: It fails with the same error when loading private key in Eclipse "Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)" on MacOS HighSierra "version 10.13.6 (17G7024)"